# Unexpected memory growth with Control.Monad foldM

Tags: haskell

I have the following code, which has been stripped down and is I think as minimal as possible that has some very odd behaviour.

The code consists of two source files:
One to define some data:

```
module MyFunction where

data MyFunction =
    MyFunction {
        functionNumber :: Int,
        functionResult :: IO String
        }

makeMyFunction :: Show a => Int -> IO a -> MyFunction
makeMyFunction number result = MyFunction {
    functionNumber = number,
    functionResult = result >>= return . show }
```

And the other is Main:

```
module Main (main) where

import System.CPUTime (getCPUTime)
import Data.List (foldl')
import Data.Foldable (foldlM)
import Control.Monad (foldM)
import MyFunction

exampleFunction = do
    --let x = foldl' (\a b -> a `seq` (a + b)) 0 [1..20000000]      -- This works
    --x <- foldlM (\a b -> a `seq` return (a + b)) 0 [1..20000000]  -- This works (*)
    x <- foldM (\a b -> a `seq` return (a + b)) 0 [1..20000000]    -- This doesn't
    print x
    return ()

runFunction fn = do
    result <- functionResult fn
    duration <- getCPUTime
    if result /= "()"
        then putStrLn ""
        else return ()
    putStrLn (show (fromIntegral duration / (10^9)) ++ "ms")
    return fn

main = do
    runFunction (makeMyFunction 123 exampleFunction)
    return ()
```

The code as above (compiled using GHC 7.10.3 with stack 1.0.0 with default flags) has a rapid increase in memory usage (exceeding 1GB), and takes typically 3.3 seconds.

If I make a changes to the code, for example:

- Use one of the commented alternatives to the problem line
- Take out any line from `runFunction`

The memory usage will remain minimal, and takes only about 1 second.

One feature that I think is most surprising to me is that replacing `foldM` with `foldlM` (which as far as I know `foldM = foldlM`) fixes the problem.

Also making changes to code that I don't see has any relationship to the problem lines of code also fixes the problem.  For example removing the last putStrLn.

**Another oddity is that if I merge the MyFunction module into the Main module, while it doesn't fix the problem, it actually causes `foldlM` to behave as `foldM` using excessive memory.**

In the real code that this came from, I have a large number `exampleFunction`s, and there is significantly more `Main` code, and every so often I encounter this sort of unexplained memory usage from functions, that can usually be resolved by some sort of voodoo.

I'm looking for an explanation for the behaviour.  If I know why this occurs I can then look into avoiding it.  Could this be a compiler issue, or maybe just a misunderstanding on my part?

**(*) I've highlighted the secondary issue that causes the same memory growth to occur with foldlM.**

Comment: The fact that moving things between modules affects behavior *strongly* suggests that GHC's inliner is involved. Most likely, some transformation enabled by inlining is either *helping* you or *hurting* you.

Comment: an unrelated issue is your arithmetic in exampleFunction is getting defaulted to Integer which will be quite slow. Turn on `-Wall`.

Comment: @jberryman exampleFunction is intended to be an example only - to show the memory increase.

Comment: Check out the compiling both the foldM and foldlM versions with `ghc --make -fforce-recomp -Wall -O1 -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -ddump-inlinings -ddump-rule-firings -ddump-to-file` and gvimdiff the *.dump-simpl and *.dump-inlinings files. In your slow version lists aren't getting fused away (you can grep for ":"). You could try to puzzle out why this happened if you like doing this sort of thing, but better to report a bug I think.

Comment: Both monadic versions exhibit the same behavior (~2GB memory usage) on my system. Are you sure that `foldlM` uses less memory?

Comment: @Zeta Yes I have just copied the exact code above to verify, and foldlM uses less memory.  This is on windows if it makes any difference.

Comment: (Forgot to say: I replicated the runtime difference you saw between the synonymous foldM/foldlM versions with 7.10, on linux; this is basically just an inlining/list fusion bug that should be reported to lib maintainers)

Comment: @jberryman so are you saying this is a library issues and the problem is specific to these functions?

Comment: @pticawr yes I think so; the primary difference I saw in your slow version is that the intermediate list is not fused away, which is all a library-level issue: it's controlled with rewrite rules and INLINE pragmas (which can be both quite brittle, and difficult to understand). The authors would I think like to know how `foldlM` did not exhibit the same behavior as `foldM` w/r/t inlining and optimization.

Comment: @pticawr: My bad. I used `ghc -prof`, and apparently `foldM` takes the same time as `foldlM` in a profiled build. Your observation holds (am also on Windows).

Comment: Maybe this question should be retitled, something like "Unexpected memory growth with Control.Monad foldM"?

Comment: I noticed something similiar when using `foldM` to implement a [BF interpreter](https://github.com/frerich/brainfuck/blob/master/src/Data/Language/Brainfuck/Interpreter.hs#L31): it is a very tight loop, and the fact that `foldM` didn't get inlined greatly slowed things down.

Answer (score 3):

Here is `foldlM` from `Foldable.hs` (ghc)

```hs
-- | Monadic fold over the elements of a structure,
-- associating to the left, i.e. from left to right.
foldlM :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b
foldlM f z0 xs = foldr f' return xs z0
  where f' x k z = f z x >>= k
```

and `foldM` from `Monad.hs`

```
foldM          :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b
{-# INLINEABLE foldM #-}
{-# SPECIALISE foldM :: (a -> b -> IO a) -> a -> [b] -> IO a #-}
{-# SPECIALISE foldM :: (a -> b -> Maybe a) -> a -> [b] -> Maybe a #-}
foldM          = foldlM
```

I placed these definitions to a separate module Test and tested the execution with and without INLINEABLE / SPESIALISE lines. Whatever the reason is, leaving out the SPECIALISE directives helped and the execution time and memory usage was like with foldlM.

After a little bit more digging, removing line

```
{-# SPECIALISE foldM :: (a -> b -> IO a) -> a -> [b] -> IO a #-}
```

effected the most.

Comment: The reason is that things marked `SPECIALIZE` are compiled specialized to the given type, and when that type is seen at use sites the specialized version is used; GHC (generally?) does *not* consider inlining instead. For something as simple as `foldM`, specialization seems almost certain to be worse than inlining in general, so those pragmas should be removed.

Comment: @dfeuer ; J.J. :  While removing the specialisation resolves one problem (when using the source files as above).  Can you explain why the problem returns when merging the source files into one, but for both foldM and foldlM showing memory usage growth?

Comment: @pticawr without optimization flag like `-O1`?

Comment: @pticawr, the inliner is a scary, hairy beast. I seem to recall that things marked `INLINEABLE` are *not* inlined in the modules in which they're defined, but I could be remembering wrong. The inliner is scary and subtle because it's based on various heuristics that aim to enable as many useful transformations as it can without making code size explode. It usually works, but when it doesn't you lose. It tends to be especially touchy around things like list fusion.

Comment: Disabling optimization (-O0) does not resolve this - only effect is that it takes twice as long.

Comment: @dfeuer, my problem here is that if I saw this sort of inconsistent behaviour from say a C++ compiler, I would consider it to be a compiler bug.  Being unable to predict what the compiler will do seems a problem.  Is there something fundamentally wrong with using foldM over a large list?  In some cases I have had to nest foldM across a partitioned list to minimize the memory impact.  Is there a reliable alternative?

Comment: @pticawr, writing everything out with explicit recursIon is generally reliable, but it's also painful. I wish I could tell you there's a magic bullet somewhere, but I haven't found one.